# Set duplicate elements as zeros

Tags: python, numpy

How can I convert the duplicate elements in a array 'data' into 0? It has to be done row-wise.

```
data = np.array([[1,8,3,3,4],
                 [1,8,9,9,4]])
```

The answer should be as follows:

```
ans = array([[1,8,3,0,4],
             [1,8,9,0,4]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

One approach with [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
# Find out the unique elements and their starting positions
unq_data, idx = np.unique(data,return_index=True)

# Find out the positions for each unique element, their duplicate positions
dup_idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(data.size),idx)

# Set those duplicate positioned elemnents to 0s
data[dup_idx] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: data
Out[46]: array([1, 8, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 9, 4])

In [47]: unq_data, idx = np.unique(data,return_index=True)
    ...: dup_idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(data.size),idx)
    ...: data[dup_idx] = 0
    ...: 

In [48]: data
Out[48]: array([1, 8, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0])
```

**Approach #2**

You can also use `sorting` and `differentiation` as a faster approach -

```
# Get indices  for sorted data
sort_idx = np.argsort(data)

# Get duplicate indices and set those in data to 0s
dup_idx = sort_idx[1::][np.diff(np.sort(data))==0]
data[dup_idx] = 0
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [110]: data = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))
     ...: data1 = data.copy()
     ...: data2 = data.copy()
     ...: 

In [111]: def func1(data):
     ...:     unq_data, idx = np.unique(data,return_index=True)
     ...:     dup_idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(data.size),idx)
     ...:     data[dup_idx] = 0
     ...: 
     ...: def func2(data):
     ...:     sort_idx = np.argsort(data)
     ...:     dup_idx = sort_idx[1::][np.diff(np.sort(data))==0]
     ...:     data[dup_idx] = 0
     ...:     

In [112]: %timeit func1(data1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop

In [113]: %timeit func2(data2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 467 µs per loop
```

---

**Extending to a 2D case :**

Approach #2 could be extended to work for a 2D array case, avoiding any loop like so -

```
# Get indices  for sorted data
sort_idx = np.argsort(data,axis=1)

# Get sorted linear indices
row_offset = data.shape[1]*np.arange(data.shape[0])[:,None]
sort_lin_idx = sort_idx[:,1::] + row_offset

# Get duplicate linear indices and set those in data as 0s
dup_lin_idx = sort_lin_idx[np.diff(np.sort(data,axis=1),axis=1)==0]
data.ravel()[dup_lin_idx] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [6]: data
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 8, 3, 3, 4, 0, 3, 3],
       [1, 8, 9, 9, 4, 8, 7, 9],
       [1, 8, 9, 9, 4, 8, 7, 3]])

In [7]: sort_idx = np.argsort(data,axis=1)
   ...: row_offset = data.shape[1]*np.arange(data.shape[0])[:,None]
   ...: sort_lin_idx = sort_idx[:,1::] + row_offset
   ...: dup_lin_idx = sort_lin_idx[np.diff(np.sort(data,axis=1),axis=1)==0]
   ...: data.ravel()[dup_lin_idx] = 0
   ...: 

In [8]: data
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 8, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 8, 9, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0],
       [1, 8, 9, 0, 4, 0, 7, 3]])
```

Comment: @jean Something like the just added second approach?

Comment: @jean Yes, you can use `np.in1d`: `dup_idx = ~np.in1d(np.arange(data.size),idx)` to get the mask of such non-unique positions. Something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple pure-Python way to do it:

```
seen = set()
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    if x in seen:
        data[i] = 0
    else:
        seen.add(x)
```

Comment: This is the only good solution here

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested for loop, where you compare each element of the array to every other element to check for duplicate records. Syntax might be a bit off as I am not really familiar with numpy.

```
for x in range(0, len(data))
   for y in range(x+1, len(data))
      if(data[x] == data[y])
         data[x] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

@Divakar has it almost right, but there are a few things that can be further optimized, but don't really fit in a comment. To begin:

```
rows, cols = data.shape
```

The first operation is to sort the array to identify the duplicates. Since we will want to undo the sorting, we need to use `np.argsort`, but if you want to make sure that it is the first occurrence of each repeated value that is kept, you need to use a stable sorting algorithm:

```
sort_idx = data.argsort(axis=1, kind='mergesort')
```

Once we have the indices to sort `data`, to get a sorted copy of the array it is faster to use the indices than to re-sort the array:

```
sorted_data = data[np.arange(rows)[:, None], sort_idx]
```

While the principle is similar to that in using `np.diff`, it is typically faster to use boolean operations. We want an array full of `False` where the first occurrences of each value happen, and `True` where the duplicates are:

```
sorted_mask = np.concatenate((np.zeros((rows, 1), dtype=bool),
                              sorted_data[:, :-1] == sorted_data[:, 1:]),
                             axis=1)
```

We now use that mask to set all the duplicates to zero:

```
sorted_data[sorted_mask] = 0
```

And we finally undo the sorting. To revert a permutation you can sort the indices that define it, i.e. you could do:

```
invert_idx = sort_idx.argsort(axis=1, kind='mergesort')
ans = sorted_data[np.arange(rows)[:, None], invert_idx]
```

But it is more efficient to use assignment, i.e.:

```
ans = np.empty_like(data)
ans[np.arange(rows), sort_idx] = sorted_data
```

Putting it all together:

```
def zero_dups(data):
    rows, cols = data.shape
    sort_idx = data.argsort(axis=1, kind='mergesort')
    sorted_data = data[np.arange(rows)[:, None], sort_idx]
    sorted_mask = np.concatenate((np.zeros((rows, 1), dtype=bool),
                                  sorted_data[:, :-1] == sorted_data[:, 1:]),
                                 axis=1)
    sorted_data[sorted_mask] = 0
    ans = np.empty_like(data)
    ans[np.arange(rows)[:, None], sort_idx] = sorted_data

    return ans
```