# How to turn duplicates in a python list into zeros

Tags: python-3.x

**I have already tried many times to solve this problem but got stuck please help.**

**The problem is that I can't make my program turn duplicates from a user's inputted list into zeros like shown in the example below.**

```
'''
Write a program that will read in a list of numbers and will then print out
the same list
except for numbers that have already been printed will be printed as a zero instead.
Example:
Input: 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 3 2 6        Output: 1 2 0 3 0 4 5 0 0 0 6 
'''

# inputs
num_input = int(input('How many numbers do you want to input? '))

# setting the array to nothing before it gets filled
numbers = []

# repeat process num_input amount of times
for i in range(num_input):
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

    # filling the arrays
    numbers.append(num)

# show list with Duplicates
print(numbers)

#numbers that have been duplicated
dups = list(set(numbers))
print(dups)

zeros = []


    # setting the array to nothing before it gets filled
    numbers = []

    # repeat process num_input amount of times
    for i in range(num_input):
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

        # filling the arrays
        numbers.append(num)

    # show list with Duplicates
    print(numbers)

    #numbers that have been duplicated
    dups = list(set(numbers))
    print(dups)

    zeros = []
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set duplicate elements as zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096939/set-duplicate-elements-as-zeros) There are both NumPy and pure Python solutions.

Comment: dups are not the duplicate items, it's unique items that may be duplicated.

Comment: Also: [Replace duplicate items from list while keeping the first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54037427/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 6]

out = []
already_appended = set()

for num in lst :
    if num in already_appended :
        out.append(0)
    else :
        out.append(num)
        already_appended.add(num)

print(out)
```

Comment: Better to make `already_appended` a set rather than a list, for efficient membership tests.

Comment: what does     already_appended = set()      mean I don't understand it.

Comment: It creates an empty `set` called `already_appended` @Illusion_421

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. You have the right ideas, but didn't connect them up in quite the right way. Check this out:

```
# setting the array to nothing before it gets filled
numbers = []

# repeat process num_input amount of times
for i in range(num_input):
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

    # filling the arrays
    numbers.append(num)

seen = set()
for num in numbers:
    if num not in seen:  # if we haven't printed this before
        print(num)  # print it, and now track it
        seen.add(set)
    else:  # we've already printed this before
        print(0)  # so print 0
```

Comment: what did you mean by seen = set() I don't understand what this does.

Comment: `set()` creates an empty set. It's the same as `set([])`